# Error con python y MySQL

Tags: mysql, python, sql, unix, pycharm

ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

```
    def refresh_acount(self):
    # actualizar cuenta:
        upgrade_balance = "UPDATE usuarios SET saldo = saldo - %s WHERE usuario = %s "
        upgrade_balance_values = (self.quanty, self.username)
        cursor.execute(upgrade_balance, upgrade_balance_values)
        database.commit()
        cursor.close()
        database.close()
        validation = cursor.fetchone()


    return [validation, self]
```

Comment: Me parece que el error ocurre porque estás haciendo esto `validation = cursor.fetchone()` luego de haber cerrado el cursor. Es ilógico, debes ponerlo antes de cerrarlo, justo después del `commit`

Comment: lo he corregido y sigue habiendo el mismo problema, se queda atascado en un consulta...